# Inheriting Variables in Java

Tags: inheritance

So I understand that a parent class will give all of its variables (and methods) to the child class. My question is am I getting a compiling error? Shouldn't the variable called number which I set as 5 in class b be inherited into class a? My code is below.

```
public class a 
{
    public static void a()
    {
        System.out.println(5*number);

    }
}

public class b extends a 
{
    public static void b()
    {
        int number = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: number is not defined anywhere in the parent class "a"

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the program. I have comented and corrected. Hopefully the essence of the what you want to achieve remains.

```
public class A {

    int number = 1; // declare the number variable

    // remove the static - cannot have an instance variable in a static block and a constructor does not return anything
    public  A() 
    {
        System.out.println(5*number);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A instance = new A();
        B child = new B();

    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        number = 5 * number; // if you want to inherit then you need to not declare a local variable here.
        System.out.print("In B : " + number);
    }
}
```